Could not load file or assembly ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.XmlSerializers
I've upgraded ArcGIS Pro from 3.2 to 3.3. To adjust the AddIn I develop, I've upgraded it from .NET 6 to 8, and I made all necessary updates. Now, while running it, before ArcGIS Pro opens, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.XmlSerializers,
Version=13.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86,
processorArchitecture=AMD64'. The system cannot find the file
specified.

This was the same before the upgrade of my ArcGIS libraries (including ArcGIS.Desktop.Core) from 13.2 to 13.3 and after it.
I'm in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. The solution is 64 bit (x64).
I've tried different debugging options. Without "Suppress JIT optimization on module load", ArcGIS Pro starts. It's still buggy, but I assume the other errors are not connected to this one. So, I understand I've found a workaround, but I'd prefer a clean solution. Any suggestion?

In the upgrade process from .NET 6 to .NET 8, I forgot to update the desktopVersion in the Config.daml and the <RuntimeIdentifier> in each project's .vbproj file. There are still errors, but they are no longer fatal, even with the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option on.
